# precedence of persistence.xml in hibernate project

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, orm, jpa, classpath

I have an eclipse project with several jars for JPA / Hibernate. One of tham contains a `META-INF/persistence.xml` and I want to override that by defining my own `persistence.xml`. So I tried  using my `persistence.xml` in `src/persistence.xml` also `src/META-INF/persistence.xml` but everytime it seems `jar/META-INF/persistence.xml` gets picked up.
I also tried editing **`.classpath`** file of eclipse projects and moved up **`classpathentry path="bin"`** higher up than the library included but still its not picking up my `persistence.xml`

```
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/java"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/rules"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="DROOLS/Drools"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.USER_LIBRARY/drools"/>
</classpath>
```

In the tutorial I read:

> You will need to override these
>   defaults if you want to change them,
>   by adding your own persistence.xml in
>   your classpath, preceding the default
>   one in drools-persistence-jpa.jar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So I tried using my persistence.xml in src/persistence.xml also src/META-INF/persistence.xml but every time it seems jar/META-INF/persistence.xml gets picked up.

The `persistence.xml` should be located under `META-INF/persistence.xml` so the first attempt won't work. And when I look at your `.classpath` file, I don't see `src` as source path so the second attempt won't work either.

Try `src/main/java/META-INF/persistence.xml` instead.

Actually, your project layout really looks like a Maven layout and with Maven, resources typically go to `src/main/resources` or `src/test/resources`. But since you didn't mention what tutorial you're following, I can't confirm if this applies here.

Anyway, my suggestion should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked. I assumed /src/ was classes folder. So my META-INF/persistence.xml was not getting copied to the /bin/ folder at all. So that was kind of stupid question. Anyways this is the tutorial regarding Drools flow [url]http://downloads.jboss.com/drools/docs/5.1.1.34858.FINAL/drools-flow/html_single/index.html#d0e1699[/url]